# Is there a type-safe version of Choose()?

Tags: vb.net

In the VS2008 version of the VB compiler, the [`IIf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.iif.aspx), which always returns an object and does not short-circuit, has been replaced by the new, short-circuiting, type-inferring [`If` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx):

```
Dim x = IIf(True, "a", "b")   ' yields an Object
Dim y = If(True, "a", "b")    ' yields a String
```

Is there a similar, modern replacement (i.e., a short-circuiting, type-inferring version) available for the [`Choose` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/824bz7dy.aspx)? Or is it a compatibility relic that should not be used anymore?

```
Dim x = Choose(1, "a", "b", "c")   ' yields an Object
Dim y = ...?
```

Comment: couldn't you just cast the result of `If` to object?

Comment: more context would be helpful too!

Comment: @DanielA.White: Is my question unclear? I'm asking whether there is a short-circuiting, type-inferring version of Choose available. I'll try to clarify that in my question.

Comment: I don't think so. You may have to resort to SELECT CASE

Comment: I've been programming in VB for over 10 years and I had never heard of this function. After reading about it, I can't see any use for it either. Can you explain why you need to use it?

Comment: @MattWilko I found it useful inside of LINQ queries e.g. http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/12/17/linq-truly-language-integrated/

Comment: Are you sure it does not return the correct type?  i.e.  try msgbox(Choose(3, 1, 2.5, "C").GetType.ToString).  Change the first parameter and see what you get...

Comment: @MattWilko: One use case is to map something that is stored as `1, 2, 3, ...` internally into a user-readable string.

Comment: @APrough: GetType returns the *dynamic* type, which is obviously `String`. I'm taking about the *static* type: `Dim x As String = Choose(1, "a")` yields a compile-time error with `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in function, but you can easily implement your own:

```
Function Choose(Of T)(index As Integer, ParamArray args As T()) As T
   If index < 1 OrElse index > args.Length Then
      Return Nothing
   Else
      Return args(index - 1)
   End If
End Function
```

Give it a try

```
Dim y = Choose(1, "a", "b", "c")   ' yields an string
```

Comment: That should be `Dim y = Choose(Of String)(1, "a", "b", "c")` in your usage otherwise you are using the built in method

Comment: @MattWilko Actually, even without specifying the type it will prefer this function over built-in one, but I agree, specifying the type is better, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Like it, but what about choose statements with multiple types, or even worse, functions.  e.g. Choose(3, GetFuncA(3), 2.5, "C")?

Comment: Nice one! Won't short-circuit, but at least you avoid the cast.